# Limit the number of hex digits with string formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, hex, printf, string-formatting

I am displaying values in hex within my project of 4 characters as the value is 16bit.  In this instance the values are also signed and this is where my problem lies.

My code:

```
int16_t i = -4;
printf("i = %04x\n", i);
```

Output:

```
i = fffffffc
```

What I would like is the hex output to remain only 16-bit and not switch to a 32-bit representation.  Which it does for positive values.

Desired output:

```
i = fffc
```

Is there a nice way of specifying the total number of hex digits, or locking the output to be the same as the minimum?  (Ideally without having to resort to manipulating the value as a string :) )

Oh, I also thought this might be a compiler thing, as I 1st experienced it within Visual C++, but testing with `GCC` gave the same results under Linux.

Comment: The cause here is that `i` gets promoted to `int` for the call to `printf`, and, apparently, `int` is 32 bits wide on your system.

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker with that gem I figured a "fix" and have added it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The C style output with `printf()`

The specifier `"%x"` is for unsigned integers. Your `int16_t` gets an integer promotion in the call, and  the signed number `-4` is encoded in binary as integer `fffffffc` that is then taken as such.

The problem with [specifier "%x"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is, that the size and precision in the formatting string are minimum numbers of digits.  So it's not possible to force the formatting to truncate the output.  However, you can force the expected result with a [binary-and](http://www.somacon.com/p125.php) (operator `&`) :

```
printf("i = %04x\n", i & 0xffff);  // put as much f as digits you want to keep
```

#### C++ style output

With c++ streams you can also format into hexadecimal with [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/):

```
cout<<setw(4)<< setfill('0')<<hex<<i<<endl;
```

The ostreams do not perform the integer promotion and just use the type of the value that you output.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/9BGokj)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pete Becker for explaining the root cause: The `int16_t` is being promoted to `int` which on my system is 32-bit, hence negative numbers having a 32-bit hex representation.  By casting `i` to `uint16_t` within the `printf` the sign is hidden from the `int` and formatting of the hex is as desired.

```
int16_t i = -4;
printf("i = %04x\n", (uint16_t) i);
```

Output:

```
i = fffc
```